# kotlin, how to make a internal function also able to be override in a sub class (in other module)

Tags: kotlin, derived-class

android project has multiple modules. module A has some base class in kotlin

```
package xxx.module_a

open class InModule_A {
   protected function action() {...}
}

class Runner() {

    fun doSomething() {
        InModule_A().action(). // it is NOT compile, but if the action() is internal it is ok since they are in same module
    }

}
```

in module A the `Runner` class need to access the `InModule_A()` class member function `action()`.

And the `InModule_A.action()` should only be visible inside the `module A` and to be overridden in its derived classes in other module.

In `module B`, it has class `InModule_B` derived from `InModule_A`.

```
package xxx.module_b

class InModule_B {

   protected override function action() {// if InModule_A().action() were a internal it would not be able to override here 
   
   super.action()
   ... ...
   }
}
```

how to make function has internal visibility and also to able to override in the derived class?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand, but maybe creating an alternate function that calls through to the protected function would fit your situation.

```
open class InModule_A {
    protected open fun action() {}
    internal fun internalAction() = action()
}

class Runner() {

    fun doSomething() {
        InModule_A().internalAction()
    }

}
```

Comment: thx! looks like that is the only option unless bigger refactoring.